# How to get the first value of Arraylist

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, android-activity

I am working on map v2. I wanted to convert latitude and longitude into the text address.So i used Geocoder class to locate the address. Now the problem is when i used List, it gives so many confusing locations. It might be the list of locations. I want to retrieve just the first location among them and pass that location to another activity. How can i do that? Please help.Its an emergency.Below is my code:

```
  try {
    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
      List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation( dmylats,  dmylong,  1);         

      if (addresses.size() > 0) 
          Toast.makeText(this, "You are at "+addresses,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

I just want the first value among the List.

Comment: So what's wrong with `addresses.get(0)`?

Comment: `addresses.get(addresses.size() - 1 )` ?

Comment: And please be clear as to which value you want? First or last?

Comment: @ dhruti sorry for the inconvinient question...i wanted the first value. and pass that value into another activity..plz can u help me for that..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android/7325248#7325248

Comment: @Dhruti ..when i tried to use addresses.get(0)....it gave me following error:   09-17 06:48:05.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1704): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: @mystic_knight That means that arraylist has no data at all. Please debug and check why you are not getting data.

Answer (score 4):

This can be archived via

```
addresses.get(addresses.size()-1)
```

Edit: The title said "*last* value" before OP's edit...

To answer the new question:

```
addresses.get(0)
```

Comment: how can i pass that address string into another activity...plz tell me if u know

Comment: @mystic_knight You should open a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
addresses.get(addresses.size()-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            // Get the location manager
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
                Location location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double lon = location.getLongitude();
                Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
                List<Address> lstAdd = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
                Address ad = lstAdd.get(0);
                String str = ad.getAddressLine(0);
            TToast.makeText(this, "Your current location is " + str,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: it gives an error :    09-17 06:35:13.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1602): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: Means that array list has no data.. Please check your code and manifest permissions.